# How to prolong a straight line in either direction using mapbox gl

Tags: geospatial, mapbox-gl-js

I have a straight line defined by 2 points (x1,y1 and x2,y2) drawn with mapbox gl. Now I want to prolong this line. The new line should overlay the old one.

To draw this new line I need a JS-function like:

```
prolongLine((x1, y1, x2, y2, direction, length);
```

where **direction** is first point, second point or both
and **length** is the length of the prolongation

The result should again be a longer straight line added in a new layer. Everything is in the range below 1km.

After exercising and searching very long I got desperate.

Answer (score 0):

```
drawProlongation(id,x1,y1,x2,y2,length)  {
    x3 = parseFloat(x1) + (parseFloat(x1) - parseFloat(x2));
    y3 = parseFloat(y1) + (parseFloat(y1) - parseFloat(y2));
    x4 = parseFloat(x2) - (parseFloat(x1) - parseFloat(x2));
    y4 = parseFloat(y2) - (parseFloat(y1) - parseFloat(y2));
    wSourceId = "proSource"+id;
    wLayerId = "proLayer"+id;
    // Remove map layer & source. if exists
    var mapLayer = map.getLayer(wLayerId);
    if(typeof mapLayer !== 'undefined') {
      map.removeLayer(wLayerId);
      map.removeSource(wSourceId);
    }
    map.addSource(wSourceId,{
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
        'type': 'LineString',
        'coordinates': [ [x3,y3],[x4,y4] ]
        }
           }
    });
    // Add .
    map.addLayer({
      'id': id,
      'type': 'line',
      'source': wSourceId,
      'layout': {},
      'paint': {
      'line-color': '#bb0',
      'line-width': 2
      }
    });

    
},
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).